# Como devolver um conjunto de elementos como uma string única?

Tags: python-3.x, string

Eu encontrei este exercício no Code Wars onde esperam receber uma só string, que será um número de telefone, com o seguinte formato:

```
"(294) 926-8617"
```

Mas o melhor que consigo fazer é sem as aspas:

```
(294) 926-8617
```

O meu código é este:

```
import random as rd

def create_phone_number(n):
    b = ""
    for number in range(len(n)):
        a = rd.choice(n)
        b += str(a)
        if len(b) == 10:
            print('(', end='')
            print(''.join(map(str, b[:3])), end='')
            print(')', end=' ')
            print(''.join(map(str, b[3:6])), end='-')
            print(''.join(map(str, b[6:])))


n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

create_phone_number(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é só adicionar dois prints com uma aspas em cada um?

Assim:

```
#aspa no começo
print('"', end='')

print('(', end='')
print(''.join(map(str, b[:3])), end='')
print(')', end=' ')
print(''.join(map(str, b[3:6])), end='-')
print(''.join(map(str, b[6:])), end='')

#aspa no final
print('"')
```

Ou poderia concatenar todas variáveis e valores assim:

```
phone = '"('
phone += ''.join(map(str, b[:3]))
phone += ') ' + ''.join(map(str, b[3:6])) + '-'
phone += ''.join(map(str, b[6:])) + '"'
print(phone)
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu problema está em não saber como acrescentar as aspas, basta você colocá-las no início da primeira impressão e no `end` da segunda impressão, dessa forma:

```
if len(b) == 10:
    print('"(', end = '')
    # Outros prints ...
    print(''.join(map(str, b[6:])), end = '"')
```

Uma outra coisa também que você pode fazer, é tornar o seu código **muito** menor e muito mais simples. Basta utilizar o método [`format()`](https://w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) para definir como a sua string irá ficar e depois, passar o valores como parâmetro.

Além disso, a sua função deveria criar um número de telefone e não imprimir um número. Você poderia então retornar a string com o número de telefone criado. Veja abaixo:

```
def create_phone_number(n):

    numbers = [rd.choice(n) for i in range(10)]
    return '"({}{}{}) {}{}{}-{}{}{}{}"'.format(*numbers)

n = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

phone_number = create_phone_number(n)
print(phone_number)
```